# How do i peek at at the next value of string iterator

Tags: c++, string, iterator

In a loop running over the entire `string` how do i peek at the next value of iterator?

```
for (string::iterator it = inp.begin(); it!= inp.end(); ++it)
{
  // Just peek at the next value of it, without actually incrementing the iterator
}
```

This is quite simple in C,

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {
     if (str[i] == str[i+1]) {
         // Processing
     }
}
```

Any efficient way to do above in c++?

Note: Im not using Boost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Peek the next element in STL container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673684/peek-the-next-element-in-stl-container)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ( not imp.empty() )
{
    for (string::iterator it = inp.begin(); it!= inp.end(); ++it)
         if (it + 1 != inp.end() and *it == *(it + 1)) {
             // Processing
         }
    }
}
```

or

```
if ( not imp.empty() )
{
    for (string::iterator it = inp.begin(); it!= inp.end() - 1; ++it)
        if ( *it == *(it+1) ) {
            // Processing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid deferencing past the end (which causes Undefined Behaviour) by using `if (it + 1 != inp.end() && *it == *(it + 1))` instead. -1 to get your attention, will revoke when fixed.

Comment: Actually, I now see that both ways will technically cause UB for an empty string. (Technically it's UB if you advance past one-past-the-end of a sequence/array, or back before the beginning -- even if you don't deref the iterator/pointer.) Sorry to nitpick...

Answer (score 2):

`string` happens to provide a random-access iterator, so `operator+(int)` exists.  You can use Shmoopty's answer, nice and easy.

If you were using `list<>`, which only provides a bidirectional iterator, you'd keep a second iterator around.

```
for (list<char>::iterator it(inp.begin()), next(it);
        it != inp.end() && ++next != inp.end(); it = next) {
    if (*it == *next) {
        // Processing
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. And unlike Shmoopty's loops (which I suggested and thus share blame for) this correctly handles the empty-container boundary case.