# Peeking the next element in STL container

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Is it possible to peek next element in a container which the iterator currently points to without changing the iterator?

For example in std::set,

```
int myArray[]= {1,2,3,4};
set <int> mySet(myArray, myArray+4);
set <int>::iterator iter = mySet.begin();

//peek the next element in set without changing iterator.

mySet.erase(iter); //erase the element if next element is n+1
```

Comment: Why not just make a copy and advance that one? Make sure you check if either iterator is equal to `.end()` before you continue!

Comment: I think I was confusing the iterator with a pointer. when you assign a pointer to pointer, both will change if one pointer changes but why it doesn't happen in the case of an iterator?

Comment: @GMan: Boost has `prior` and `next` functions for doing just that (it takes the iterator by value, thus making a copy as you suggested). See http://www.boost.org/libs/utility/utility.htm for details.

Comment: @xor: If you have two pointers, and change one of them, the other stays the same. Understand, though, that we're talking about changing the pointer, not the pointer's referent.

Comment: I mean int *i = new int(5);

 int *j = i;

 *i = 6;  here j changes with i.

Comment: @xor: You should be careful how you describe things. Strictly speaking, what you've said is wrong. `j` does not change with `i`, it's a different variable who's value is no way tied to that of `i`. What `j` *points* to changes, and it just so happens `i` points there as well.

Comment: Ah I get it, we're changing the pointer or iterator after the assignment but not the value itself it points to.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not with iterators in general. An iterator isn't guaranteed to be able to operate non-destructively. The classic example is an Input Iterator that actually represents an underlying input stream.

There's something that works for this kind of iterator, though. A [Forward Iterator](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ForwardIterator.html) doesn't invalidate previous copies of itself by the act of moving forward through the collection. Most iterators (including those for STL collections) are at least Forward Iterators, if not a more functional version- only Input Iterators or Output Iterators are more restricted. So you can simply make a copy of your iterator, increment the copy and check *that*, then go back to your original iterator.

So your peek code:

```
set <int>::iterator dupe = iter;
++dupe;
// (do stuff with dupe)
```

Answer (score 29):

C++0x adds a handy utility function, `std::next`, that copies an iterator, advances it, and returns the advanced iterator.  You can easily write your own `std::next` implementation:

```
#include <iterator>

template <typename ForwardIt>
ForwardIt next(ForwardIt it, 
               typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::difference_type n = 1)
{
    std::advance(it, n);
    return it;
}
```

You can use this in your example like so:

```
if (iter != mySet.end() && next(iter) != mySet.end() && *next(iter) == *iter + 1)
    mySet.erase(iter);
```

Comment: +1, didn't know that was adopted. Incidentally, `++ move( iter )` does the same thing.

Comment: I'm not an expert with templates so it took me a while to fully grok this small bit of code and almost went with the easier solution provided by @AndrewShephard. But at the last minute noticed that this solution is functionally the same (but not identical) to gcc's 4.4.x and 4.9.x source code located at `/usr/include/c++/${gcc_version}/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h` and so I went with this solution instead.

Comment: I see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next says it's since c++11, which is correct?

Comment: @zhangxaochen: C++0x was the working title for C++11 (before the schedule slipped, when they though it would be released before 2010); C++0x and C++11 really mean the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

```
set <int>::iterator iter2 = iter;
++iter2;
int peekedValue = *iter2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always make a copy of the iterator and advance the copy:

```
set <int>::iterator iter = mySet.begin();
set <int>::iterator iterCopy = iter;
iterCopy++;
if (*iterCopy == something)
  mySet.erase(iter);
```

But beware that `iterCopy` may no longer be valid once you erase `iter`.

Comment: "iterCopy may no longer be valid once you erase iter".  It will be for a set, but not for all STL containers.  I google "SGI STL set" or whatever when I want a good reference... covers all this.

Comment: Be aware, however, that SGI is a great resource for the STL.  It isn't entirely accurate as far as the C++ standard library is concerned, however.  The STL contains several non-standard containers/algorithms, and the containers that are part of standard C++ don't match up on some of the details, particularly with regard to allocators.

Answer (score 0):

for sequence containers (vector, deque, and list) you can call front which will give you a peek (more info on the lower part of this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/)).

Answer (score 0):

This will not work for `std::set` as its nature does not allow for the [] operator, but for containers that do, you can do:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(3);
v.push_back(4);
std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); 
std::cout << v[it - v.begin() + 1];
```

But this could be dangerous if `it` points to the last element in the container; but the same applies to the solution above. E.g. you'll have to make checks in both cases.

Comment: Why use `operator[]` when you already have an iterator?  If you want what `it` currently points to, use `*it`.  If you want what the iterator after `it` points to, use something like `*(it + 1)` or `std::vector<int>::iterator it2(it); std::advance(it2, 1); *it2;`.Incidentally, the code presented will only work for a `std::vector` (it won't work with a `std::deque` for instance).