# How do I get the second element in a standard list

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using a list in the c++ standard library and I want to know how can I get the 2nd element with an iterator. I have two iterators and I want iterator 2 to be 1 node ahead.

```
intPaint(string input){
list<char>sequence (input.begin,input.end);
int count;
list<char>::iterator ptr1= sequence.begin();
list<char>::iterator ptr2= ?// I want to get the second node
...//rest of the code isn't important it just checks the characters and moves
//the iterator
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Peek the next element in STL container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673684/peek-the-next-element-in-stl-container)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are indeed using C++11, then `std::next()` should do the trick:

```
list<char>::iterator ptr1 = sequence.begin();
list<char>::iterator ptr2 = std::next(sequence.begin())
```

From the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/next/):

```
template <class ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator next(ForwardIterator it,
                     typename iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::difference_type n = 1);
```

> Get iterator to next element. Returns an iterator pointing to the
>   element that it would be pointing to if advanced n positions.

Comment: thanks although that didn't do the job that I wanted but thank you anyways

Comment: That's kind, but if the answer is wrong I can delete or fix it :-) Do you mean it answers the question correctly, but your question isn't the way forward for your actual problem?

Comment: No I tried it but for the problem I was trying to use a list for turns out to not work and soI need to use a different data structure.